# Edit email Header from CLI

Tags: linux, command-line, email, unix, alpine-mail

I am trying to find a cli bincode to allow me to manipulate email headers from an IMAP server.

Something like Alpine, but with header editing functionality, like subjects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mutt, <kbd>e</kbd> (bound to `edit`) will open the raw downloaded message for editing, and will automatically re-upload the edited version.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! II just choose Alpine over Mutt because I've read that Mutt is "unconfigurable". Well, let's see if that's true. ;-) I'll check later this evening.